# How to search for any unicode octal character in a buffer?

Tags: search, replace, unicode

I'm looking for a way to locate all unicode octal characters in a buffer such as \344 and replace them with ä or \353 with ë, etc.

At the least if I could just locate octal characters using incremental search or a REGEXP search, I could manually replace them.

Answer (score 2):

Use `query-replace` (`M-%`). When entering the string to replace or the replacement string, you can enter a character using its octal code either of these ways:

- Type `C-q` followed by the octal digits - e.g. `C-q 344`
- Type `C-x 8 RET #o` followed by the octal digits - e.g. `C-x 8 RET $=#o344`

The same possibilities exist for inserting a character to search for during Isearch.

But be aware that octal 344 ***IS*** ä - they are exactly the same character. So I expect that you are asking the wrong question.

It's possible that your buffer is in unibyte mode or its encoding or current font does not let the normal glyph (e.g. ä) for the character be displayed, so it is displayed instead using octal escape syntax (e.g. \344).

(It is unlikely that you have a unibyte buffer.  But to ensure that your it is not unibyte, set buffer-local variable `enable-multibyte-characters` to `t`. See  (elisp) [Disabling Multibyte](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Disabling-Multibyte.html) for how to tell if your buffer is unibyte.)

(ASCII control characters, such as CONTROL A, are also displayed as octal escapes, if variable `ctl-arrow` is `nil`.  But that is irrelevant for the characters you are asking about - they are not ASCII control characters.)

Answer (score 0):

You can insert characters by their octal code points with <kbd>C-q</kbd>.

From docstring for `quoted-insert`:

> If the first character you type after this command is an octal digit,
>   you should type a sequence of octal digits which specify a character
>   code. Any nondigit terminates the sequence.  If the terminator is a
>   RET, it is discarded; any other terminator is used itself as input.